# Mail URI with special chars - The hostname could not be parsed

Tags: c#, email, uri

I'm trying to create a new Uri() from the following email:

user+26/6@gmail.com

Via:

```
var x = new Uri("mailto:user+25/6@gmail.com");
```

But I keep getting:
"The hostname could not be parsed"

If I send a message to that kind of email it gets delivered. I've seen it throws the exception as soon as it sees the combination of "+" and "/" on the email.

Any ideas how to bypass it?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri?view=net-5.0) "/" is special character for Uri Class. You can try using "\/" instead

```
var x = new Uri("mailto:user+25\/6@gmail.com");
```

to avoid it but I didn't tested.

Comment: Nope. Stil throws same exception